# Python battleships: getting a user input for how many ships they want

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to get the game to take an input for how many ships the user would like, and to place that many ships. I have put the coordinates into a list and that is how I am storing them, and checking if it is a hit. But the ships get placed over each other, and with this list method, I don't know how to first of all, check they are not overlapping, and second of all, change it so they aren't.

```
    from random import randint
    print('Welcome to Battleships for 1 player! Please be careful with entries, as if you get it wrong, you will still lose a go!')
    print('Good luck!')
    print('')
    no_of_goes = int(input("How many goes would you like: "))
    size_of_board = int(input("And how big would you like the board to be: "))
    if size_of_board > 56:
        print("That board will be too big to fit on the screen (max 56)")
        size_of_board = int(input("And choose a more sensible number: "))
    no_of_ships = int(input("And finally, how many ships would you like?: "))
    board = []
    # printing out the board
    for x in range(size_of_board):
        board.append(["O"] * size_of_board)

    def print_board(board):
        for row in board:
            print ("  ".join(row))
    print_board(board)
    # the lists that will become the locations
    ship_rows = []
    ship_cols = []
    # generating random locations
    def random_row(board): 
            return randint(0, len(board) - 1)

    def random_col(board):
            return randint(0, len(board) - 1)
    # adding locations to lists
    ships = list(range(no_of_ships))
    for i in ships:
        row = random_row(board)
        col = random_col(board)
        ship_rows.append(row)
        ship_cols.append(col)
        ##
        ## And this is my attempt (didn't work)
        ##
        for row in ship_cols:
            if row == ship_cols and col == ship_cols:
                ship_rows[-1] = random_row(board)
                ship_cols[-1] = random_col(board)            
    # allowing to see where ships are and logging how many ships have been hit
    print(ship_rows)
    print(ship_cols)
    ship_count = [1]
    ## I couldn't find a way of ending the game once the ships were sunk, so I stuck in a recursive function (sorry)
    def printing_stars():
        print('You have won!! ' +'*' * 56)
        printing_stars()
    for turn in range(no_of_goes):
        # asking for their guesses
        print('Turn ' + str(turn + 1) + ' out of ' + str(no_of_goes))
        guess_col = int(input("Guess Col:")) - 1
        guess_row = int(input("Guess Row:")) - 1
        for item in ship_rows:
            # If they hit, it gives a '!'
            if len(ship_count) == no_of_ships and guess_row == item and guess_col == ship_cols[ship_rows.index(item)]:
                print("You have won!!!! Congratulations")
                board [guess_row][guess_col] = '!'
                print_board(board)
                printing_stars()

            elif guess_row == item and guess_col == ship_cols[ship_rows.index(item)]:
                print ("Congratulations! You sunk one of my battleships")
                board [guess_row][guess_col] = '!'
                print_board(board)
                ship_count.append(1)
                break    
        else:
            # all misses
            if (guess_row < 0 or guess_row > size_of_board - 1) or (guess_col < 0 or guess_col > size_of_board - 1):
                print ("Oops, that's not even in the ocean.")

            elif board[guess_row][guess_col] == "X" or board[guess_row][guess_col] == "!":
                print ("You guessed that one already.")
                turn -= 1
            else:
                print ("You missed my battleship!")
                board[guess_row][guess_col] = "X"
            print_board(board)
            if turn == (no_of_goes - 1):
                print('Game Over')
                break
```

Any ideas? Would be very grateful :)

Comment: is this from codecademy?

Answer (score 0):

Some suggestion for your code :

You could model the player board with a numpy array like this :

- Size : i lines and j colums => (i, j)
- 0 if water
- 1 if water that was shot by the palyer
- 2 if ship unharm
- 3 if ship case is hit

Once they are no more 2, it means there is a winner.
With this system, you can tell a player if he is shooting twice the same spot and you could also generate a display.

Moreover, to randomly position the ship, you could use this procedure :

- Set ship size : let's say 4 spots.
- Choose randomly 0 or 1 : 0 to place the ship horizontaly, and 1 to place the ship verticaly

Now we have to look if it is placed horizontaly or verticaly. 
If it's horizontaly placed :

- Choose 2 random number between 0 and j-4 and 0 and i. That will be your ship first spot coordinate, it means, this spot turn to 2, and the 3 spot on after it also.

Example with a 5*5 board, and a position pick of (1,0) for an horizontal ship

```
 00000
 22220
 00000
 00000
 00000
```

- I let you take care of the case verticaly, just have to change the random number generation indices.

Then that solution doesn't prevent from getting a ship on an other one. One simple solution, is with this loop :

```
while True:
    if all ship placed:
        break

    pick number
    Try to place the ship. (with an if statement, check if one of the spot your gonna change is already a 2.)
```

That solution should work as long as it is possible to place all the ship on the board. If it's impossible, you'll the loop won't end. Moreover if the number of ship is not limited in regard of the board size, it could be long to place them.

You can then keep improving the method with more complicated scenario. One other solution would be to check after each ship positioning where you still have place to put one.

Comment: Thank you so much for the input! But if it was going to be a valid game, having a 2 as an unharmed ship would defeat the point of guessing where it is wouldn't it? Or it this just how the computer sees it and not how it would appear on the console

Comment: Of course you don't show it like that ! For the computer, you store the data like that, for the user, you create a display_matrix that will show the exact same thing but while replacing the 2 by 0, so the ship stay hidden, and so that you can still see where you shoted.